# How to map HashMap of String and ArrayList of Strings using morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Currently, I am trying to save a map of string and ArrayList of string as:

```
@Embedded("prprty")
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> prprtyMap;
```

But trying to save it results in Exception

```
com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error mapping field:roposo.roposocore.models.ScheduleStoryMongo.prprtyMap
        at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:542) ~[com.google.code.morphia.morphia-0.102.jar:na]
        at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:522) ~[com.google.code.morphia.morphia-0.102.jar:na]
        at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.entityToDBObj(DatastoreImpl.java:775) ~[com.google.code.morphia.morphia-0.102.jar:na]
        at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:836) ~[com.google.code.morphia.morphia-0.102.jar:na]
        at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:913) ~[com.google.code.morphia.morphia-0.102.jar:na]
        at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:898) ~[com.google.code.morphia.morphia-0.102.jar:na]
```

What is the correct way to save such a map using Morphia Driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using inner class having strings required in ArrayList. 
Then, I was able to save Map using:

```
@Embedded("prprty")
private HashMap<String, InnerClassWithArrayStrings> prprtyMap;
```